# Oracle SQL: Join two queries into one result set using count() and group by()

Tags: sql, oracle, join, count, subquery

- I have two tables to select and join data from.
- Both share corresponding key values.
- The select statement of the second table shall count() and group by() values.

An example and the expected result shall explain the situation:

**Table One**

```
| id  | rev | colour |
| --- | --- | ------ |
| 1   | a   | blue   |
| 2   | a   | green  |
| 1   | b   | grey   |
```

**Table Two**

```
| id  | rev | note     |
| --- | --- | -------- |
| 1   | a   | rejected |
| 1   | a   | removed  |
| 1   | b   | rejected |
| 1   | b   | rejected |
| 2   | a   | removed  |
| 2   | a   | removed  |
```

**Pseudo SQL of the expected result set**

t1.id, t1.rev, t1.colour, t2.count(rejected), t2.count(removed)

**Expected result**

```
| id  | rev | colour | rejected | removed |
| --- | --- | ------ | -------- | ------- |
| 1   | a   | blue   | 1        | 1       |
| 2   | a   | green  | 0        | 2       |
| 1   | b   | grey   | 2        | 0       |
```

What is the best way to get this in one SQL Statement?
I guess I should use two sub-selects and join those. Don't know how
to put in the count(), group by() and join here.

Thanks for your ideas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just want aggregation and `join`.  I would approach this as:

```
select *
from table1 t1 left join
     (select id, rev,
             sum(case when note = 'rejected' then 1 else 0 end) as rejected,
             sum(case when note = 'removed' then 1 else 0 end) as removed
      from table2 t2
      group by id, rev
     ) t2
     using (id, rev);
```

Doing the aggregation in the subquery and using the `using` clause makes it convenient to select all columns from `table1` without having to list all of them.

Comment: Using count is more clear than sum in this case and count never returns null. count(case when note 'rejected' then 1 end)

Comment: @akk0rd87 . . . I much prefer `sum()` in these cases, because an `else` clause throws off the `count()`.  Also, `count(2) = count(1)` and I think that is rather confusing to explain to people learning SQL.